# How to define Golang struct map property using Terraform provider framework?

Tags: go, terraform

In the [Terraform tutorial](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/providers-plugin-framework/providers-plugin-framework-data-source-read#implement-data-source-data-models) for creating a custom provider using their provider framework, they describe the need to create a struct that will be mapped to and from a schema.

The example below shows this:

```
// coffeesDataSourceModel maps the data source schema data.
type coffeesDataSourceModel struct {
  Coffees []coffeesModel `tfsdk:"coffees"`
}

// coffeesModel maps coffees schema data.
type coffeesModel struct {
  ID          types.Int64               `tfsdk:"id"`
  Name        types.String              `tfsdk:"name"`
  Teaser      types.String              `tfsdk:"teaser"`
  Description types.String              `tfsdk:"description"`
  Price       types.Float64             `tfsdk:"price"`
  Image       types.String              `tfsdk:"image"`
  Ingredients []coffeesIngredientsModel `tfsdk:"ingredients"`
}
```

Note the use of TF’s `types.X` types.

How do I define an additional property in `coffeesModel` that is a map of strings to some other object using types.Map?

e.g. I want a property foo that is a map of strings to objects of type bar?